# In PrimeFaces how to show a confirm close window when closing a dialog box?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have requirement where in there is a Main dialog box and when I am trying to close it, it should show close confirmation popup(its also another dialog box). When I say YES in confirmation window, it should close the main dialog and when said NO it should keep the main dialog window as it is.

Comment: And your actual coding problem is?

Comment: How to show Confirmation window on click of close of Main dialog?

Comment: No, that is your functional problem... There are examples about using confirm dialog in PrimeFaces showcase, there are examples on stackoverflow. Did you try those? Any errors? Real problems?

Answer (score -1):

With PF 3.4.1, this should give you two dialogs, where the yes on the confirm dialog will close both of them and no will close the confirm, but leave dialog 1 visible.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="wvDlg1" ... >
    <p:commandButton value="Close?" onclick="wvDlgConfirm.show();"/>
    <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="wvDlg1.hide();"/>
</p:dialog>

<p:confirmDialog> widgetVar="wvDlgConfirm" ... >
  <p:commandButton value="Yes" @process="this"  action="{bean.doConfirmStuff}"
      oncomplete="wvDlgConfirm.hide(); wvDlg1.hide();"/>
  <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="wvDlgConfirm.hide();"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Each `widgetVar` is a variable in the Primefaces Javascript namespace, so you can call `widgetvar.show();` or `widgetvar.hide();` as needed.

Comment: How does it work (if at all) when I use the 'close' button at the top-right corner of the dialog?